# Plus one button share option makes an empty post

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I have implemented the +1 button on my app following these really simple instructions https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend. I am passing my app url as the url and 0 as the PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE. I think the +1 part is working although I'm not certain but the share part is odd. Basically it shares whatever I type or nothing if I don't type anything but it doesn't share the URL. Seems kind of useless! Anyone else have this issue?

Thanks.

EDIT: code

On create:

```
 plusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
```

on resume:

```
plusOneButton.initialize(myapplink, 0);
```

button:

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
                    android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    plus:size="standard"
                    plus:annotation="inline" />
```

EDIT: I should also point out that I tried this on another application (not mine) using the same button and it had the same issue. So maybe that is the default behavior but it seems like it is useless behavior.

Comment: Please post your code to help us better assist you.

Comment: Added it now. Didn't add it before because it is just a copy of that link I posted.

Comment: What link did you mean to include?

Comment: Totally forgot the link. I've just added it. Thanks for letting me know. https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend

Comment: did you find something? I have same issue.

Comment: No, I just stopped using the button eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Use a builder for share.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.share_button:
      PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(this);

      // Set call-to-action metadata.
      builder.addCallToAction(
          "CREATE_ITEM", /** call-to-action button label */
          Uri.parse("http://plus.google.com/pages/create"), /** call-to-action url (for desktop use) */
          "/pages/create" /** call to action deep-link ID (for mobile use), 512 characters or fewer */);

      // Set the content url (for desktop use).
      builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/pages/"));

      // Set the target deep-link ID (for mobile use).
      builder.setContentDeepLinkId("/pages/",
              null, null, null);

      // Set the share text.
      builder.setText("Create your Google+ Page too!");

      startActivityForResult(builder.getIntent(), 0);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't really want to have a share as a separate item, I just want the one that comes with the +1 button to do something useful.

Comment: Ok. This is for you when you want your own button. The original one looked bad in my design so I made my own.

Comment: I really only wanted the +1 but it came with a share option on its own. I guess maybe I can make my own +1 button or is that not possible?

Comment: of couse, I used the same code as above minus the deeplink, as that was not needed.  See here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/